# Calculate last year group by ID with DAX

Tags: filter, ssas, dax, ssas-tabular, measure

I have a table in SSAS Tabular Model like this

```
Table 1
    ID      END DATE 
    1       06/24/2016  
    1       06/24/2017  
    1       06/24/2018  
    2       08/08/2017  
    2       08/08/2016  
    3       12/12/2015
```

I would like to create a Mesure in DAX, in another related Table. The output should be this:

```
Table 2
ID  MAXYEAR
1    2018
1    2018
1    2018
2    2017
2    2017
3    2015
```

PLEASE !!!  WITHOUT USING EARLIER. Because my model is very large, and can´t use this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a relationship between the 2 tables, assuming that Table 2
   contains unique values for ID.

[image]

2. Create a year column from end date

```
Year = year([END DATE])
```

4. After that, in Table 2 create a calculated column with the following code:

```
MaxYear = CALCULATE(max('Table'[Year]))
```

Table 2 should look like this

[image]